# Oracle: Replace all characters by star except first 3 letters of each words

Tags: regex, oracle

In ORACLE I would like to replace all chararacter of each words by star except the 3 first letters.

*Example*

Before:

> `Company Microsoft Technology`

After:

> `Com**** Mic****** Tec*******`

I think I can use the `REGEXP_REPLACE` function. Thanks a lot

Comment: yes, you are right, you can use `REGEXP_REPLACE`.

Comment: I had the idea of optionally capturing each first three word characters and use those in replacement: [`((\W|^)\w{3})?\w` and replace with `\1*`](https://regex101.com/r/Wnj8N7/1) but this would also [cloak words with less than 3 characters](https://regex101.com/r/Wnj8N7/3), which is probably not intended as @MT0 mentioned, so I put it as a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each non-white-space substring of each sentence and then concatenate the previous part of the sentence with the first up-to-3 character sub-string and then the rest of the word replaced with `*` (you can use `LPAD( '*', length, '*' )` for that` and then the resto of the sentence and perform that iteratively, which you can do in a recursive sub-query factoring clause:

**Test Data**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_data ( value ) AS
 SELECT 'Company Microsoft Technology' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT ' a bb ccc dddd eeeee' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT 'Smith-Smythe O''Brien' FROM DUAL
```

**Query**:

```sql
WITH bounds ( value, start_pos, end_pos ) AS (
  SELECT value,
         1,
         1
  FROM   test_data
UNION ALL
  SELECT SUBSTR( value, 1, start_pos - 1 )
         || SUBSTR( value, start_pos, LEAST( end_pos - start_pos, 3 ) )
         || LPAD( '*', GREATEST( 0, end_pos - start_pos - 3 ), '*' )
         || SUBSTR( value, end_pos ),
         REGEXP_INSTR( value, '\S+', end_pos, 1, 0 ),
         REGEXP_INSTR( value, '\S+', end_pos, 1, 1 )
  FROM   bounds
  WHERE  end_pos > 0
)
SELECT value
FROM   bounds
WHERE  end_pos = 0;
```

**Output**:

> ```
> | VALUE                        |
> | :--------------------------- |
> | Smi********* O'B****         |
> | Com**** Mic****** Tec******* |
> |  a bb ccc ddd* eee**         |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5c29c650c2ef673a722ea6dd0a5e19bb)*

Comment: Thanks a lot MT0

Answer (score 1):

Yet another approach (thank you, MT0, for test case and comments you already posted).

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (SELECT 'Company Microsoft Technology' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  3     SELECT ' a bb ccc dddd eeeee'         FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  4     SELECT 'Smith-Smythe O''Brien'        FROM DUAL
  5    ),
  6  tsplit as
  7    (select regexp_substr(col, '[^ ]+', 1, column_value) val,
  8            column_value rn,
  9            col
 10     from test cross join table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 11                                              connect by level <= regexp_count(col, ' ') + 1
 12                                             ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 13    )
 14  select
 15    listagg(case when length(val) > 3 then substr(val, 1, 3) || lpad('*', length(val) - 3, '*')
 16                 else val
 17            end, ' ') within group (order by rn) result
 18  from tsplit
 19  group by col;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
a bb ccc ddd* eee**
Com**** Mic****** Tec*******
Smi********* O'B****

SQL>
```

Comment: This stripped the leading space from the ` a bb ccc dddd eeeee` row and would replace multiple spaces with a single space. May not matter to the OP but it can introduce small changes other than masking the words.

Comment: Slightly more complicated but you can do it by splitting and re-aggregating the string - [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=48b99f459d3da489b28f6ba7c5d38006)

Comment: Huh, right, didn't even notice the leading space, @MT0, sorry. Thank you for the Fiddle! The OP got their answer so that would be it, I presume.